# I can't figure out why the counter works on one button but not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to Javascript and JQuery and i can't seem to figure out why the counter increments for one button but the same code doesn't work for the others. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
// JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY (to increment by 1)
let addRoom = document.querySelector(".addRoom");
let subtractRoom = document.querySelector(".subtractRoom");
let input = document.querySelector(".roomsAmmount");

addRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
});

subtractRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
});
```

```css
/*.addRoom,.subtractRoom{position:absolute;font-size:1.3em;width:50%;height:45px;z-index:1;display:flex}.roomsAmmount{position:absolute;width:50px;height:45px;right:-60px;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #f4b494;outline:0;font-size:1.4em;text-align:center;background-color:transparent;color:#fff}
*/
```

```html
<div class="bedroomsButton">Bedrooms
  <div class="addRoom">
    <span class="plusOne">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtractRoom">
    <span class="subtractOne">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="roomsAmmount" type="number" value="0">
</div>

<div class="bathroomsButton">Bathrooms
  <div class="addRoom">
    <span class="plusOne">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtractRoom">
    <span class="subtractOne">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="roomsAmmount" type="number" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Because `document.querySelector()` returns *either* the first element in the document that matches the supplied selector or `null`. Since you have multiple elements to target you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()`, and then select the relevant input element within your functions. Also, and irrelevant to your problem since you’re consistent, the word “amount” in the English language only has a single “m” not double (but as noted you’re consistent in your use, so it’s irrelevant except as a perceived typo).

Comment: Ah thanks! Although that now gives me the error message ".addEventListener is not a function" do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You aren't actually using jQuery _at all_. All of your code is plain JavaScript.

Comment: Apologies, there is further JQuery up the page, i just pasted the code i was having  
 a problem with as to not over crowed the page.

Answer (score 2):

[**Document.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method `querySelector()` ***returns the first Element*** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors

You can target all the elements with [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop through them using [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to attach the event handler.

```js
// JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY (to increment by 1)
let addRoom = document.querySelectorAll(".addRoom");
let subtractRoom = document.querySelectorAll(".subtractRoom");

addRoom.forEach((el)=>{
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let input = e.target.closest('.bedroomsButton,.bathroomsButton').querySelector(".roomsAmmount");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  });
});

subtractRoom.forEach((el)=>{
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let input = e.target.closest('.bedroomsButton,.bathroomsButton').querySelector(".roomsAmmount");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="bedroomsButton">Bedrooms
  <div class="addRoom">
    <span class="plusOne">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtractRoom">
    <span class="subtractOne">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="roomsAmmount" type="number" value="0">
</div>

<div class="bathroomsButton">Bathrooms
  <div class="addRoom">
    <span class="plusOne">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subtractRoom">
    <span class="subtractOne">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="roomsAmmount" type="number" value="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

like the comment says, `document.querySelector` only returns either first element or null.

Do so:

```
let addRoom = document.querySelectorAll(".addRoom");
let subtractRoom = document.querySelectorAll(".subtractRoom");

addRoom.forEach(btn => {
    setInputValue(btn, true)
  }
)

subtractRoom.forEach(btn => {
    setInputValue(btn, false)
  }
)

function setInputValue(btn, plus) {
  const input = btn.parentNode.querySelector('input')
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const originalValue = parseInt(input.value)
    input.value = String(plus ? originalValue + 1 : originalValue - 1)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

add class `clickable` to every + and -

select all `clickable` and add event listener on every element

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.clickable`).forEach(el => el.addEventListener(`click`, handleClick))
```

`handleClick` function look like this

```
const handleClick = (e) => {

  // selecting a closest input
  const input = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".roomsAmmount");

  // parsing value 
  let newValue = parseInt(input.value);

  // if clicked element has class plusOne
  if (e.target.classList.contains(`plusOne`)) {
    newValue++; // increase
  }

  // if clicked element has class subtractOne
  if (e.target.classList.contains(`subtractOne`)) {
    newValue--; // decrease
  }

  // update value
  input.value = newValue;

}
```

working example https://jsfiddle.net/yqp5zx1b/1/

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate the feedback